# Continue Button not moving to next section

Tags: checkout, magento-1, onepage-checkout

I was currently working on adding a module to my site that added another step to the checkout process and after a lot of time and a lot of problems popping up, I decided to delete all the files attached to said module.  Since then I've gotten everything working properly except now at the Onepage Checkout, I've gotten stuck at the Billing section.  When I press "Continue" it does not go to the next section and the page doesn't update at all.  I believe it has something to do with the `onclick='billing.save()'` function attached to the "Continue" button.

```
<div class="buttons-set" id="billing-buttons-container">
    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
    <span class="please-wait" id="billing-please-wait" style="display:none;">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

```
var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

//billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
$('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
```

**EDIT**

Here's a link to my site. http://www.avantalarm.com/

---

<sup>NB. I am new to StackExchange and new to Magento. Let me know if I need to explain further information.  I'm very interested in learning how to phrase my questions well so I can get the most out of Stack Exchange.</sup>

Comment: Check for javascript errors and/or the ajax response for the save billing action. Use Firebug for that. A link to your website would help a little.

Comment: Thanks.  I added a link to the site and I also checked for JS errors.  It says `Type Error: checkout is undefined onclick() anonymous()`  I am pretty sure that the JS for opcheckout.js is being loaded in the head however, so I'm curious why this wouldn't work when this JS is in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a javascript error in the checkout page: `ReferenceError: Excellence is not defined`.
This comes from this code:

```
var checkout = new Excellence(accordion,{
        progress: 'https://www.avantalarm.com/checkout/onepage/progress/',
        review: 'https://www.avantalarm.com/checkout/onepage/review/',
        saveMethod: 'https://www.avantalarm.com/checkout/onepage/saveMethod/',
        failure: 'http://www.avantalarm.com/checkout/cart/'}
    );
```

Instead of `new Excellence(...` it should be `new Checkout(...`

You should make the change in this file `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` (at the end of the file)

Comment: My Onepage checkout like same error, but without any changes after 5 min everything good, back to normal working. Is advisable to update your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem also. After a lot of time investment /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtm i have changed this line

```
 <fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
 </fieldset>
```

to

```
 <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
 </fieldset>
```